# DefaultRollback after running all test cases

Tags: java, spring, junit, testng

I have an Integration test as shown below, and I want to rollback the changes to the database after going through the test cases. Now my question is is there a way to prevent default rollback from happening after each test case and have a roll back once all the test cases are done.

After surfing a bit I found that TestNG can be helpful, but I don't want to use that. Is there any other alternative?

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "myTransactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class TestDependencies extends testBase {

  @Test
  public void testSetupData() throws SQLException, Exception{
      //Some initial setup code.
  }

  @Test
  public void testFunctionality throws Exception{
      //here i will further test some more functionality
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your test cases that require rollback are in one class, the junit @afterclass annotation will run this method after all @test methods are executed.

```
@AfterClass 
public static void Cleanup() {
      txManager.rollback();
}
```

txManager should be wired up to your DataSourceTransactionManager bean.